# How can I hide node titles only for displayed nodes, and not node edit forms?

Tags: theming

I have a little function to hide my node titles via template.php:

```
function mytheme_alpha_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'episode') {
    $vars['title_hidden'] = TRUE;
  }}
```

This function hides the title on the node edit form too, but for that form I need a title.

How can I avoid changing the node edit form in my function?

Answer (score 5):

You could add a check to see if you are editing the node, like

```
function mytheme_alpha_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'episode') {
    if(arg(2) != 'edit') {
        $vars['title_hidden'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I was looking for hours, but couldn´t get it right. Your solution does the trick (and it looks so easy).

Comment: If this is the answer you're looking for it you should mark it as such.